# Zend framwork routeing for get the url from the server

Tags: php, zend-framework

This my Zend Form

```
public function init()
{
    $this->setName('PackRpm');

    $ID = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('ID');
    $ID->addFilter('Int');

    $release_version = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Release_Version');
    $release_version->setLabel('Release_Version')
                    ->setRequired(true)
                    ->addFilter('StringTrim');

    $search = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('Search');
    $search->setAttrib('ID', 'searchbutton');
    $search->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));

    $this->addElements(array($ID, $Release_Version, $Search));
}
```

This is my simple form. Now i want build my controller and view.

Now my question is:
 Let's say I have one server name is http://my.server.com/release here i have set of release version packages with name of release-1.noarch.rpm,release-2.noarch.rpm, and so on...

Now using zendframework how to i configure the Route for access server http://my.server.com/release using view form i want search rpm whether it is available or not.

could you please some one help on this ?